# jQuery and wordpress question.. Compare link title to text in certain div and if equal add a class to list item

Tags: jquery, each

I've had a programming problem that's driving me crazy for the last few days. I've searched through the wordpress doc and there's no way to do it via php but I know it can be done client side. In the sidebar of my application I have a list of all the post titles and a link to each.

```
.nav li a
```

I then have a div lets call it .random. This div has text in it... So what I'm trying to do is..

If the title of .nav li a is equal to

```
$('.random').text()
```

I'd like to add a class to that link.

Unfortunately I seem to be struggling with the ".each()" function in jQuery to get this to work.. Any help would be much appreciated!..

Comment: Can you show us the full jquery code that you currently have?

Answer (score 2):

Just

```
$(".nav li a[title="+$('.random').text()+"]").addClass('myclass');
```

?

But if `$('.random').text()` has character like ] it will be an issue.

**Edit**

To solve this issue you could either escape it, or use a filter :

```
$(".nav li a").filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr("title")==$('.random').text();
}).addClass('myclass');
```

Or a each :

```
$(".nav li a").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("title")==$('.random').text()) $(this).addClass('myclass');
});
```

Comment: i think if $('.random').text() contains a " or ' it will cause a problem, but if it contains a ] then it should be fine

Comment: @Johnny Craig.. Code works great.. Quick question if I want to change it so that instead of li a[title] is EQUAL (==) to .random text, li a[title] CONTAINS ('.random').text()...

Comment: My apologies Johnny.. I'm a noob

Comment: regardless,  change a[title=   to   a[title*=  (if your using my code and comment in the wrong spot)

Comment: $(".nav li a").each(function(){
   if($(this).attr("title")==$('.random').text())
    $(this).parent().addClass('current_page_item');  
});  This is the one I'm trying to work with. I want to see how to solve it by checking if the title CONTAINS random.text() rather than being explicitly equal... My apolgies for being a noob once again..

Comment: and in the other solutions, you can change `$(this).attr("title")==$('.random').text()` by `$(this).attr("title").match($('.random').text())`

Answer (score 0):

this may work, if i understand correctly

```
var r = $('.random').text();
$('a[title*="' + r + '"]').addClass('newclass');
```

edit to new value of $('.random').text()

edited again to change class if link title contains $('.random').text()

Comment: How can I change it so that instead of == i want it to check if it just contains .random's text.. Sorry I'm a noob on this site..

Comment: var r = $('.random').text();
$('a[title*="' + r + '"]').addClass('newclass');

will work